# Prove standard deviation $=\sqrt{npq}$

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, binomial-distribution

In class we learnt that for a binomial experiment, the standard deviation is equal to $\sqrt{npq}$. Is there a way to derive/prove this? I have a basic understanding of standard deviation and binomial but have no idea where to start in this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Derive with direct computation the variance $σ^2$ of Bernoulli(p). You will find that it is equal to $p(1-p)$. Then, write the Binomial$(n,p)$ denoted with $X_n$ as the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli$(p)$, $X_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ 
$$X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ and use the formula $$σ^2_n=\sum_{i=1}^nσ^2_i=\sum_{i=1}^np(1-p)=np(1-p)$$ Now, to find the standard deviation $σ_n$, just take the root of the previous expression.

Comment: I have only a high school of understanding of mathematics I am currently on year 12, is there a simple or inituitive way to prove/understand the formula or is this the only way? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there are other ways, but I am not sure. Make sure you can calculate the variance of a Bernoulli random variable, as I say in the first step.

Comment: This is not the only way, but it is the easiest way.  An alternative is to find $\displaystyle \sqrt{\dfrac1n \sum_{m=0}^n \left(m - \dfrac1n  \sum_{k=0}^n k \, {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \right)^2  \, {n \choose m} p^m (1-p)^{n-m}}$